# Weak derivative of $|x|^{-\lambda}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

We're supposed to show that for $\lambda\geq d-1$, there does not exist a weak derivative $v\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of $|x|^{-\lambda}$. Im really stuck here. Here's what I came up with so far: Let $\phi\in C_c^\infty$ and $R>0$ large enough, such that $\mathrm{supp}(\phi)\subset B(0,R)$. Now let $1\leq j\leq d$. I want to show that for $\lambda\geq d-1$, $|x|^{-\lambda}\partial_j\phi$ is not integrable and I figured that if it fails to be so, it's going to be at the origin. Hence by choosing $R$ as above I don't have to worry about the terms outside of a large enough ball. So
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|x|^{-\lambda}\partial_j\phi=\int_{|x|<R}|x|^{-\lambda}\partial_j\phi=\int_0^Rr^{d-\lambda-1}\left(\int_{S^{d-1}}\partial_j\phi(ry)\ d\sigma(y)\right)\ dr,
$$
where I used spherical coordinates in the last equality and $\sigma$ is the surface measure on $S^{d-1}$. Now I'd like to argue that this integral diverges because $r^{d-\lambda-1}$ is not integrable on $[0,R]$ (at least when $\lambda>d-1$). But here I don't know how to proceed. Maybe someone can give me a hint or point out a different approach that I can try: Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It seems that you are attempting to prove that the integral fails to exist for every test function. In order to show that the weak derivative doesn't exist, it suffices to find one test function for which the integral fails to converge.

Comment: Yes that was my approach. I thought briefly about the approach your talking about, but I could't find a suitable test function to get it to work.

Comment: Your approach will not work because if the test function is constant in a neighborhood of the origin, then the integral is finite. Perhaps try a test function with nonvanishing derivatives near the origin.

Comment: Ok thank youn I'll give it a try.